# I do not understand this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Language development is conceived as relative to one's own past
>   performance, or relative to that of others.

I do not understand these parts : **is conceived as relative** and **that**

I checked the dictionary.

"conceive" has different meanings:
1: to imagine a particular situation or to think about something in a particular way
2: to think of a new idea and develop it in your mind
3: to become pregnant

"Relative" has two meanings.
1: having a particular quality when compared with sth else
2: connected with a particular subject

But I am not exactly sure which meanings are correct in this context.
Unfortunately , there are no other sentences to have an educated guess.
Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Any chance you could cite a whole paragraph to give a little more context?

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is reasonable.  "Conceive" is not a good verb to use here.  I would have instead used "measured".  With that one change the sentence should make more sense:

> *Language development* is **measured** relative to one's own past performance, or relative to that of others.

It's still an awkward sentence.  I would have written it out explicitly:

> We often **measure** our "language development" relative to our own past ability in that language, or relative to the performance of others who are also learning that language.